# no voice output in Festival

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, festival

I have just installed the Festival 2.5.0, and in its interface when I type (SayText "hello"), I get no output sound at all. It only gives me this error:

festival> (SayText "hello")

FindNextComponent

Error setting input audio stream format.

#<Utterance 0x136893780>

I have tried different (Parameter.set) and all of them did not work.

However, when I type this following code, I could generate the wavefile in my local laptop and has no problem hearing it:

(set! myutt (Utterance Text "test"))

(utt.synth myutt)

(utt.save.wave myutt "myutt.wav" 'riff)

I am completely new in Festival and I have no clue why this error occurs. How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what operating system you are on, but I had the same problem on macOS. My solution was to set the following parameters from the Festival prompt:

```
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Required_Format 'riff)
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Command "afplay $FILE")
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Method 'Audio_Command)
```

After that I could say ‘hello’ with:

```
(SayPhones '(pau hh ax l ow pau))
```

If you are on Linux, you could attempt to install `sox` and replace `afplay` with `play` in the `Parameter.set` call above.